# WPF Notification Balloon using a User Control

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I am working in a WPF app in C# and it is really very very sad that WPF doesn't have a NotifyIcon like in the Win forms has. I have seen a lot of articles in the net for a wpf notifyicon balloon notification project. But none satisfied me. See, I have an idea but i don't know how to execute it.

Create a wpf user control with height and width same like the notifyicon. 
Put a border control in it with corner radius 5. Put a grid inside that border control to place the textblocks and images.

Then position that user control to the system tray area. When we click a button from a window, this user control shows up just above the system tray and it hides when we click on outside area.

Is this possible to place the user control [this new "notifyicon" ] just above the system tray area ???

Comment: `it is really very very sad that WPF doesn't have a NotifyIcon like in the Win forms has`, it has toast... Mantin has a nice library over at [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification) you could try out...

Comment: So you have checked other projects for similar purpose and techniques used in them. What is the exact bottleneck for you to create your own?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an AdornerDecorater in you XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Check this project out [GitHub](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification/#readme-body-tab).  It has a configurable notification toast popup control for WPF with a demo app.